# How to connect chrome extension with webpage like metamask?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, blockchain, metamask

I have chrome extension like Metamask, I am working on the private blockchain and developed the chrome extension wallet for this chain. Now I want to do payments using this wallet from the webpage.  So, I am not getting how to connect my webpage with this chrome extension. Just like Metamask, it should get connected on the button click from the webpage.

Comment: I don't know metamask but there are two methods: content scripts and [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage). You can also easily inspect metamask's code in devtools or inside the browser profile.

Comment: Thanx @wOxxOm, I used these methods to connect webpage with the chrome extension. But I have another question about how to access extension html elements from chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener method.